# plugin issue of flutter and dart in android studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

[output after i clicked to install plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdU7V.png)i have recently updated android studio to 3.4 because of that there is problem in plugin .It says flutter plugin is not compatible with this version of android studio .
how Can i solve this issue ?

Comment: update your flutter version

Comment: flutter version is already latest :(

Answer (score 5):

Update Flutter plugin to latest(34.0.2) version.

How I update flutter plugin version in MacOS:

- Android Studio -> Preference
- Select plugins in sidebar
- Select flutter and click update button.
- File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart.

---

Installed plugin version in Android Studio

- Dart version : 183.5901
- Flutter : 34.0.2

Comment: nothing happen broo i had mention picture above in the question please have a look at that

Comment: for me, on Mac there is no issue, try to update flutter repo along with plugin and android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the issue has been fixed. I updated the plugins and they're all working as they're supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this on android studio.

1. click on file on android studio UI
2. Go to settings and click on plugins
3. Click on installed tab
4. In the middle task pane, look for flutter and Dart and then click on update.
5. Restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like both the latest Dart and Flutter plugins are't compatible with Android Studio 3.4. I just opened up an [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3390), I see that you are also running on Linux like me, this may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually uninstalling, invalidating caches and installing the Flutter and Dart plugins again fixed the problem. This issue didn't happen for Intellij Idea so I'm guessing the problem is with Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

then

- flutter clean

if problem is not resolved, Uninstall plugins then reinstall them.
if that does not solve your problem. then  run a command

- flutter upgrade